# Center a text in a padding modified button element?

Tags: html, css, element

I've tried multiple attempts but there was no progress, my theory is that this is because of the modified padding of the element, do correct me if I'm wrong.

```
.button1{
    
    padding-right: auto;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.671);
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 50;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -20px;
    
    
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

Inside the HTML file

```
<div align="center"><a href="someurl"><button class="button1"><p align="left">Continue</p></button></a></div>
```

Comment: Validate with https://validator.w3.org/nu/ return many errors. 1. The `align` attribute on the `div` element is obsolete. 2. The element `button` must not appear as a descendant of the `a` element. 3. Element `p` not allowed as child of element `button` in this context. 4. The `align` attribute on the `p` element is obsolete.

Comment: And instead of `40px` left try a `20px` left padding and `20px` right

Comment: Adding to what @vee said, using invalid HTML is **never an option**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was from @vee :

> "Validate with validator.w3.org/nu return many errors. 1. The align
> attribute on the div element is obsolete. 2. The element button must
> not appear as a descendant of the a element. 3. Element p not allowed
> as child of element button in this context. 4. The align attribute on
> the p element is obsolete."

Comment: @MRebati (Reply to a deleted comment) Thank you for the suggestion albeit the answer was a comment. I wanted to declare this question as answered. This was to prevent any unhelpful suggestions (i.e.) yours.

Answer (score -1):

your text is not in the center because you write"alight: left" inside of the p tag. Now, Using "text-align: center" you can set text center on a button using CSS.

```css
button.button1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.671);
    border-radius: 20px;
    min-width: 95px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    line-height: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}


button.button1 p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <a href="someurl">
    <button class="button1">
      <p align="left">Continue</p>
    </button>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is equally invalid HTML, which is **never an option**.